# How to link page of product detail of Shopify admin to my app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

[https://admin.shopify.com/store/{store_name}/apps/{app_name}/test](https://admin.shopify.com/store/%7Bstore_name%7D/apps/%7Bapp_name%7D/test)

In the above link I have a link with the id of the Product. I would like to refer to the link below.
[https://admin.shopify.com/store/{store_name}/products/{product_id}](https://admin.shopify.com/store/%7Bstore_name%7D/products/%7Bproduct_id%7D)

What should I do?

{store_name} will be changed by store.
I think I will get the store name from the API and insert it into
[https://admin.shopify.com/store/{store_name}](https://admin.shopify.com/store/%7Bstore_name%7D).

But I don't like it at all.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the API packages are structured such that the store is handed to you by Shopify so you can manage to find the correct API keys you need for that store. It is not something you need to consider or change. It is the only way to ensure your App knows what to do. If you do not like it, do not make your Admin code an App, instead, just get yourself an API keypair you can use as you wish from within the store. That way, you can still program to the store, without the hassle of being in the store and having to use the embedded App pattern you do not seem to like. You lose being in the Shopify Admin to use the App, but you can make API calls to the store without the store name.